# Problems appending rows to DataFrame. ZMQ messages to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, append, zeromq

I am taking messages for market data from a ZMQ subscription and turning it into a pandas dataframe.

I tried creating a empty dataframe and appending rows to it. It did not work out. I keep getting this error.

```
RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort 
order is undefined for incomparable objects
result = result.union(other)
```

Im guessing this is because Im appending a list of strings to a dataframe. I clear the list then try to append the next row. The data is 9 rows. First one is a string and the other 8 are all floats.

```
list_heartbeat = []
list_fills= []
market_data_bb = []
market_data_fs = []
abacus_fs = []
abacus_bb =[]
df_bar_data_bb = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Ticker','Start_Time_Intervl','Interval_Length','Current_Open_Price',
                                                    'Previous_Open','Previous_Low','Previous_High','Previous_Close','Message_ID'])


def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket_sub1 = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket_sub2 = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket_sub3 = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    print('Opening Socket...')
    # We can connect to several endpoints if we desire, and receive from all.
    print('Connecting to Nicks BroadCast...')

    socket_sub1.connect("Server:port")
    socket_sub2.connect("Server:port")
    socket_sub3.connect("Server:port")
    print('Connected To Nicks BroadCast... Waiting For Messages.')
    print('Connected To Jasons Two BroadCasts... Waiting for Messages.')
    #socket_sub1.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'H')
    socket_sub1.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'R')
    #socket_sub1.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'HEARTBEAT')  #possible         heartbeat from Jason
    socket_sub2.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'BAR_FS')
    socket_sub2.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'HEARTBEAT')
    socket_sub2.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'BAR_BB')
    socket_sub3.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'ABA_FS')
    socket_sub3.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'ABA_BB')


    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket_sub1, zmq.POLLIN)
    poller.register(socket_sub2, zmq.POLLIN)
    poller.register(socket_sub3, zmq.POLLIN)




while (running):
    try:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    #check if the message is in socks, if so then save to message1-3 for future use.
    #Msg1 = heartbeat for Nicks server
    #Msg2 = fills
    #msg3 Mrkt Data split between FS and BB
    #msg4 
    if socket_sub1 in socks:
        message1 = socket_sub1.recv_string()
        list_heartbeat.append(message1.split())

    if socket_sub2 in socks:
        message2 = socket_sub2.recv_string()
        message3 = socket_sub2.recv_string()

        if message2 == 'HEARTBEAT':
            print(message2)
            print(message3)
        if message2 ==  'BAR_BB':
            message3_split = message3.split(";")
            message3_split = [e[3:] for e in message3_split]
            #print(message3_split)
            message3_split = message3_split
            market_data_bb.append(message3_split)

            if len(market_data_bb) > 20:
                #df_bar_data_bb = pd.DataFrame(market_data_bb, columns= ['Ticker','Start_Time_Intervl','Interval_Length','Current_Open_Price',
                                                  #                      'Previous_Open','Previous_Low','Previous_High','Previous_Close','Message_ID'])
                #df_bar_data_bb.set_index('Start_Time_Intervl', inplace=True)

                #ESA = df_bar_data_bb[df_bar_data_bb['Ticker'] == 'ESA Index'].copy()
                #print(ESA)
                #df_bar_data_bb.set_index('Start_Time_Intervl', inplace=True)

                df_bar_data_bb.append(market_data_bb)
                market_data_bb.clear()
                print(df_bar_data_bb)
```

The very bottom is what throws the Error. I found a simple way around this that may or may not work. Its the 4 lines above that create a dataframe then set the index and try to create copies of the dataframe. The only problem is I get about anywhere from 40-90 messages a second and every time I get a new one it creates a new dataframe. I eventually have to create a graph out of this and im not exactly sure how I would create a live graph out of this. But thats another problem.

EDIT: I figured it out. Instead of adding the messages to a list I simply convert each message to a pandas series then call my dataframe globally then do df=df.append(message4,ignore_index=True) 
I completely removed the need for lists

```
if message2 ==  'BAR_BB':
            message3_split = message3.split(";")
            message3_split = [e[3:] for e in message3_split]
            message4 = pd.Series(message3_split)
            global df_bar_data_bb1
            df_bar_data_bb1 =  df_bar_data_bb1.append(message4, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: This is basically saying that one of the comparisons involved in the last few lines was between string and numbers. Make sure you convert everything to integers?

Comment: Everything coming from ZMQ is a string by default. The first item of each list is a string and the rest are floats. Or they will be once I hard code it.

Comment: So market_data_bb is a list of strings, and df_bar_data_bb is a dataframe with multiple rows and columns? Can you provide a snapshot of what they look like?

Comment: The .... is all the columns between. its a 1x9 to start then it gets longer. Index: []
     `                              Ticker    ...     Message_ID
    Start_Time_Intervl                ...               
    1531935000          CTA Comdty    ...         191129
    1531935000          CTA Comdty    ...         191130
    1531935000          CTA Comdty    ...         191131
    1531935000          CTA Comdty    ...         191132
    1531935000          NVA Curncy    ...         191134`

Comment: Please format them in the question. This is hard to read...

Comment: Yeah, one second. I'm not very familiar with the actual formatting part of this. So i just took a snipp and used imgur. https://imgur.com/a/KwB6wcx  the ... i cant get rid of even when I set the max rows to be shown. Not sure whats going on there. but i assure you all the values there should be floats

Comment: @xyzjayne I figured it out. I turned the message into a pandas series called my dataframe globably then did df_bar_data_bb1 = df_bar_data_bb1.append(message4, ignore_index=True. I completely removed the need for lists.